# how to create a pivot/summary list from a list of model using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I created a list of model that I like to do some counting and summing on the data and return a new list with some columns and totals.

I have the following model

```
public class Employee
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string department { get; set; }
   public decimal salary { get; set; }
   public decimal sales { get; set; }

}
```

And I have a list that looks like this

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
```

I need to be able to know

1. The total of employee for each department
2. Sum of the salary

How can I Group by Department and sum the salary?

Here is what I tried

```
var totals = employees.GroupBy(x => x.department)
                      .Select(i => new 
            {
                department = i.department,
                total = i.count(),
                salary = i.Sum(c => c.salary),

            }).ToList();
```

but this code is giving me syntax error

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: You have grouped by department, so department is the key. - `department = i.Key,` (and it should be `total => i.Count(),` - uppercase C)

Comment: Thank you that fixed the syntax error. but how would I access department and total from totals?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - `var dept = totals[0].department;` will return the first department (or are you wanting to display this collection in the view, in which case you should be creating a view model and projecting the data into a collection of the view model, not using a anonymous object.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you for your help.